# Is there any tools or EDA for easily using systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

When I use systemverilog, I can not find a good IDE to show the methods of a specific object since systemverlog is a kind of OOP. So I want to know is there any easy to use IDE or tool for systemverlog code and that can also build a testbench?

Comment: Tools do exist that do what you want for SystemVerilog. Try searching for SystemVerilog IDE. (integrated development environment)

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly what you are searching for but you might have a look at a visual studio code plugin : [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mshr-h.SystemVerilog)